# How to ignore changes made in a NERD_tree windows when closing MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim with the NERD tree plugin.

When I close MacVim I get a model window saying `There are several documents with unsaved changes.` and asking me if I want to save those changes.

That's fine but something the only unsaved document is the NERD tree window. In this case the message I get is like `There are several documents with unsaved changes. Do you want to save the changes you made in the document "NERD_tree_3"?`.

Is there a way to set MacVim so that it ignores unsaved NERD tree windows when closing?

Comment: Isn't the NERDTree window supposed to be un-modifiable? I don't think you can yank/put anything in there so how did you end up with a modified NERDTree window?

Comment: Maybe it's when I create new files or directories while working on my project with mvim opened: in this case NERDTree refreshes the content of its window to display the new files/directories.